# Issue redirecting www to naked domain (Gitlab pages, Hugo static website, namecheap, let's encrypt)

Tags: redirect, hugo, no-www, namecheap, gitlab-pages

I have currently my Hugo static website hosted on gitlab pages with Let's encrypt for the SSL certificate. Both naked and www domain are enabled in gitlab pages as well as in the DNS (namecheap). I would like to redirect www to the naked domain.
I have been told to use cloudflare but I would need to use their own SSL certificate (which is apparently subpar compared to Let's encrypt (see https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/lets-encrypt-vs-cloudflare-for-https))
I also don't have access to the htaccess file in a hugo static website.I would really be grateful if someone could help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

I tried a redirect with namecheap but all my attempts have failed.

In DNS (Namecheap)
Type: URL Redirect Record 
Host: www
Value: http://example.com
I have also tried https for Value.

I expected to type www.example.com and be redirected to example.com but it's not happening.

Comment: I gave up and went through Clouflare, the redirect worked perfectly, my website is much faster. The only thing is that it's hiding my let's encrypt certificate and is showing their own shared certificate, but I can still renew Let's encrypt certificate by pausing Cloudfare.